# Django(djongo) can't connect to MondoDB Atlas after Heroku deployment

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku, djongo

I managed to get it working locally (different cluster, separate settings.py), but not after when deployed to Heroku.

**Heroku** - automatically adds DATABASE_URL config var with a postgresql, and I cannot remove/edit it.

**MongoDB Atlas** - I've set the MongoDB Atlas cluster to allow IPs from everywhere. And the password has no funny characters.

**django production settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'DBProd',
        'CLIENT': {
          'host': "mongodb+srv://XXX:YYY@ZZZ.pc4rx.mongodb.net/DBProd?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
        }
    }
}
```

I ran migrate straight after the deployment and it's all green OKs
`heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Everything works functional wise, just that the **data are not stored in the MongoDB Atlas cluster**. There are lots of posts from various sites on this, but they all have different instructions... Some of the posts I tried to follow:

- https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/use-atlas-on-heroku/
- [Django + Heroku + MongoDB Atlas (Djongo) = DatabaseError with No Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544561/django-heroku-mongodb-atlas-djongo-databaseerror-with-no-exception)
- [Connecting Heroku App to Atlas MongoDB Cloud service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159175/connecting-heroku-app-to-atlas-mongodb-cloud-service)

-- A very confused beginner

Comment: I deleted the postgresql add-on. But now I get "Server Error (500)" when I try to add data from the herokuapp. There is moments on the "MongoDB Read Write operation" chart, so I guess it's is connected but some configs aren't matching up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever lands on this. Add `'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1',` below `'host'` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, in my case, somehow Heroku added postgresql as an add-on for my app so have to delete that first.
Check Heroku documentation about postgresql and how to destroy add-on:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/438

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons

Then you need to configure MongoDB as your database by adding a `MONGODB_URI config var` with your database url. You should be ready to connect to your MongoDB now!

The following doc also helps:
https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/use-atlas-on-heroku/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30019580)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue. Everything works fine locally. The problem is when deploying on Heroku. I have added `'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'` and I have also configured MongoDB as my database by adding a `MONGODB_URI config var`. Heroku still autoconfigures `DATABASE_URL config var` with a `postgresql`, and I cannot remove/edit it.

In my Javascript code I used `fetch('127.0.0.1:8000/<something>')` which I specified in my `urls.py` and that way `views.py` read data from pymongo and returned it as a response.

After deploying my app to Heroku (and hardcoding the `127.0.0.1:8000` to `<myappname>.heroku.com`) the same fetch method seems to return [] instead of json containing values from MongoDB.

*This is the most identical issue I found in a post I hope I'm not out of subject.*